# W3C Jigsaw CSS-Validator.jar: how to pass CSS as parameter (not using file:file.css)?

Tags: css, jar, w3c-validation

I'm running a local version of W3C Jigsaw CSS-Validator, and I know that I can feed it a file path using `java -jar css-validator.jar --output=soap12 file:file.css`.

But what I'd much rather do is sending the CSS directly as an option, something like this:

```
java -jar css-validator.jar --output=soap12 --text="body { color: red }"
```

This seems to work, but the output doesn't show any validation errors:

```
$ java -jar lib/css-validator/css-validator.jar --text="body{color:red;}"
{vextwarning=false, output=text, lang=en, warning=2, medium=all, profile=css3}

$ java -jar lib/css-validator/css-validator.jar --text="unknowntag{unknownattribute:red;}"
{vextwarning=false, output=text, lang=en, warning=2, medium=all, profile=css3}
```

What am I doing wrong here?